# Как выгрузить список разделов неограниченной вложенности из бд?

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Есть такая таблица, где поле, которое имеет пустой parent_id является корневым. Поля, которые имеют parent_id = id.родительского раздела попадают в в этот родительский раздел и вложенность может быть бесконечной. Нужно выводить разделы как на 2 скриншоте (взял с яндекс почты).

Не понимаю даже за что браться, поэтому и решил обратиться за помощью, заранее спасибо!

[image: БД]

Необходимо вывести данные как здесь:

[image: Результат]

Comment: Без указания **точной** версии MySQL отвечать на вопрос не имеет смысла.

Comment: @Akina а зачем тут версия MySQL?

Comment: Хорошо, MariaDB 10.3. Надеюсь это поможет

Comment: @andreymal Да просто какие-то версии знают про рекурсивный CTE, а какие-то нет. Вопрос, конечно, содержит несколько отдельных, но первый этап - это получение из БД данных в виде, из коего удобно отображать в нужной форме.

Answer (score 0):

На правильный ответ не претендую, не хватает данных для тестирования. Но раз ваш список неограниченой вложености, то можно попробовать реализовать через рекурсию. Примерно, это будет выглядить так:

```
function rec($array = array()) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $query = "SELECT parent_id as id FROM table where id = {$value['id']}";
        $res = $conn->Execute($query);
        while ($data = $res->FetchRow()) {
            $result[] = $data;
        }
        if (is_array($result)) {
            return $result[] = rec($result);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}

$query = "SELECT id FROM table where parent_id IS NULL";
$res = $conn->Execute($query);
while ($data = $res->FetchRow()) {
    $result[] = $data;
}
print_r(rec($result));
```

Оставлю ответ в общем, может кто поправит в случае ошибок с моей стороны.

Comment: У вашего подхода есть существенный минус - N+1 запросов. Есть 2 правильных хороших способов решить эту проблему. Первый из них, выбрать всё и трансформировать полученные данные в дерево. Второй - асинхронно запрашивать дочерние элементы каждого узла по запросу пользователя.

Comment: глубина рекурсии обычно ограничена в ЯП.